# Open Document Content Type from SharePoint 2010 Library with perfect trust

Tags: document-library, content-type, document-template

I just created Document Content Type and then create new document from **New Document**. I got the popup "*Some files can harm your computer. If the file information below looks suspicious, or you do not fully trust the source, do not open the file*". I have 2 questions:

1. How can I ignore the popup? What consequence will I encounter after doing?
2. When I filled the metadata properties on the Document Content Type, I didn't find the publishing feature in order to save document back to library. Anyone know the way to create new document from SharePoint Library and save back to Library after finished filling document.

Thanks & Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

1. It is IE security issue and here is similar question with an answer on Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/59110/sharepoint-error-message-some-files-can-harm-your-computer
2. Check [Why is Word document created from template saved locally, instead of to the document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16938/why-is-word-document-created-from-template-saved-locally-instead-of-to-the-docum/16944#16944) for some additional info but generally it cannot be done

Answer (score 1):

We face the same problems in the word template document libray:

1- popup messag when click add new document " Some files can harm your computer. If the file imformation below looks suspicious, or you do not fully trust the source, do not open file."

2- Cannot upload the file to the Shared document (when i click save > click ok > the shared document open > and i cannot save the document template on it )

and my technical question for you it's required to have Office 2010 to be able to save the word template into the shared document libary or we can use office 2007 ?

Regards
hassib

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. You should be able to copy + paste this answer into a new question (you can always link to this existing question if needed). See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help.